# Linux L2 bridge blocks ip packets which are addressed to a listening port on the host

Tags: linux, ip, bridge, netfilter

On my Server I have a bunch of vms, connected by a simple L2 linux bridge to an OPNsense VM for firewalling and routing between the vms.

The `OPNsense` vm is connected via `macvtap` to the single `enp3s0` interface of the server.
The VM `vm01` which is connected via this simple l2 bridge to the `OPNsense` vm.

Bridge config of the `vm01` vm on the `hypervisor`:

```
auto br_vm01
iface br_vm01 inet manual
    bridge_ports none
```

Interface connecting `vm01` to the `br_vm01` bridge: `vnet2`
Interface connecting `OPNsense` to the `br_vm01` bridge: `vnet6`

IP of the `hypervisor` which hosts the `vm0` and `OPNsense` vm: `10.1.0.8`

I try to do the following:
I try to connect from the `vm01` vm to an open port (8080 in this case) on the `hypervisor`.
For example by doing a simple netcat.

```bsh
root@vm01:~# nc -vzw 2 10.1.0.8 8080
10.1.0.8: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [10.1.0.8] 8080 (http-alt) : Connection timed out
```

`vm01` has the necessary firewall rules on the `OPNsense` vm in order to communicate with the hypervisor. Also every other type of connection works just fine.

To diagnose this further, I did some tcpdumps on the `vnet2` and `vnet6` interfaces.
The IP packets enter just fine on the `vnet2` interface, but they are never sent out again on the `vnet6` interface. So somehow the linux bridge filters out this packet.
I also did a packet capture on the `OPNsense` vm and the packet have never arrived there.

This only happens when I try to contact the hypervisor, it never happens when I contact anything else.

My question: Is it possible to somehow tell Linux to only treat the bridge as a dumb layer 2 switch.
I do not need any kind of filtering since that is provided by the `OPNsense` vm.

Stuff I have already tried and usefull info:
`/sys/class/net/br_vm01/bridge/nf_call_iptables` is set to 0.
`sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` also shows 0.
`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables`
Turning on VLAN awareness on the bridge also did not help.
I do not have any ebtables rules.

The `hypervisor` and `vm01` are running `Debian 11` with Kernel `5.10.0-11`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

Found the answer. The problem was the way I tested the `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` param.

When I tested it, I did not only changed `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` but I also changed a bunch of other variables. This sadly made it not work. In the end it turned out that just setting that to `0` solved it.

## Reason

This still didn't explain to me to why the problem was caused though.
The problem was caused by the iptables rules of docker which seemed to mess with the bridges. The problem only occured when I tried to contact an open port on the hypervisor which was opened by docker. So it did not occur with one  which has not been opened by it, like with `nc -l -p 8081`